# Can it be possible to send push notification from one app on one device to the same app on another device in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

Can it be possible to send push notification from one app on one device to same app  on another device in Ionic 4 using Firebase Cloud Messaging?.

I'm looking forward to create a text and a simple button from one app and send FCM push notification to all the devices automatically.

Can this be done? If so, then how?

A simple example with textbox and button to submit is enough for me in Ionic 4.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Are you trying to send notification from one device and receive it on other devices where your app is installed? Because one application cannot send push notification to another application (Eg: WhatsApp can't send push notification to Facebook)

Comment: No. My question is if my app is installed on two device, then one device among those two should send push notification to other and vice versa. Suppose that app is installed on 30 devices, then if 1 person sends the push notification message then it should be received by rest 29 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send notifications from your app to other devices having your app installed.

For broadcasting to multiple devices, you would create a channel and subscribe to it.

```
push.subscribe(
  'my-topic',
  () => {
    console.log('success');
  },
  e => {
    console.log('error:', e);
  }
);
```

For sending notification to a particular device, you would require the device ID. Use [Device Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device) to get the device ID and save that to your Firebase database just like your would save username, email etc.

Read the Push notification Docs Here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md

**To send the notification, you need to make an HTTP Post request to FCM server**.

```
 this.http.post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",body,{
                headers: options.set('Authorization', 'key='+gcmKey),
              });
```

Read more about the parameters that you need to pass with it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message

Comment: Can it be possible to send push notification to the device without using device ID?? I want to simply send push notification to all the devices which have my app installed.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. You need to subscribe to a topic. In FCM, a topic is created to receive broadcasts. Please read the documents. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message  Here you will find how to send a notification to all the devices that have subscribed to a topic.